# How to make lite/pro versions of app function slightly different from the referenced library

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, multiple-apk

Right now I have 3 projects:

1. Library with all my code
2. Pro empty shell
3. Lite empty shell

I need to be able to do four things:

1. Change an `int` in library based on if user has pro or lite version
2. Change a `long` in library based on if user has pro or lite version
3. Add `ads` in the lite shell
4. Change the `launch icon`.  Not sure where to put this.  Leave both icons out of library or put both in library?
5. I have 2 `Google Analytic` codes -- one to track pro and other to track lite
6. I have a `TextView` in library right now that has a link to the pro version.  Should I leave this in the library or just make it not visible in the pro or take it out the library and only have it in the lite?

I am having trouble finding a good example of how to set up code for this sort of thing.  Do I just put logic statements somewhere in the library or do I create some java/xml files in the shells?  So right now the empty pro/lite projects just reference the library but have no jars, xml files, java files, pngs or anything else.  I have changed the two shells `AndroidManifest` package name to be unique to each project.

Comment: What have you tried then? Can't you just pass a parameter changing the mode when initialising your library from the shell? (If you can't, you should consider refactoring the library so you can.)

Comment: Also, please avoid omnibus question. It seems like this should be maybe several questions, and you haven't really shown what you've tried for either.

Comment: I was just trying to be thorough with my question.  I am really just looking for an example that I could look at.  I see many tutorials saying how to set up the structure with the 3 projects but I cannot seem to find any tutorials saying how to implement the code.

Comment: Being thorough with your question means making it *focused*, and doing as much of your own work as possible (including at least some dummy code outlining your setup) on the concern you're not focusing on. Listing off a bunch of interrelated concerns in prose then going "please send code examples" is not being thorough.

Comment: Still convinced I did it correctly since I got the exact answer I was looking for from Alexander.  Thanks anyways moose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating an Enum?

```
public enum LibType
{
  PRO(
    0,
    1L,
    "PRO"
  ),
  LITE(
    10,
    20L,
    "LITE"
  );

  public final int intVal;
  public final long longVal;
  public final String analyticsCode;

  ...

  private LibType(
      int intVal,
      long longVal,
      String analyticsCode
    )
  {
    this.intVal = intVal;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I had not heard of Enums before so I am not familiar with them but I will go read the developer docs with this example and figure it out. Thanks Alexander!